# How to identify any point inside or outside the given cone?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

The equation of a double circular cone with a vertex $p=(a,b,c)$ with the generating angle $t$ is given by

$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2= \frac{(z-c)^2}{t^2}$

How do I identify the point $A=(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$ inside or outside the given cone?

[image]

Comment: One thing you might do is find the plane passing through the axis of the cone and point A, which will give you a pair of intersecting lines (boundary of the cone). Now you can check whether A lies in the t angle of these lines. Seems a bit involved. But I am sure there is another simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Extension of the technique done in case of circles.

The cross section of the cone at $z=z_0$ is a circle, with center $(a,b,z_0)$, now check whether A is inside this circle i.e. check whether $C(a,b,z_0).C(x_0,y_0,z_0) > 0$.

Comment: it is not clear, becasue according to your argument Clearly $(a,b,c-d)$ where $d<\infty$ is inside the cone. So according to your arugment $C(a,b,c-d).C(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})>0$ is that $A$ inside the cone?